# Remove elements from python list if they contain special characters

Tags: python, list

I have a python list of lists, where each row index represents a list of values.  In some instances, the row values contain special characters.  In the case that any list element in the row contains special characters, I want to remove that entire row from the list.  Note that I want to do this without converting the list into a NumPy array or pandas data frame.  I was thinking of checking the row index that contains special characters and then just removing them this way but not sure how to do it with just a python list.  The other alternative is to convert into a NumPy array, do the data cleaning, and then convert back into the original list format but maintaining the original structure.

```py
testList = [[30.0, '?', 910.0, 120.],[11.0, 25.4, 330.3, 340.0], [1.6, 23.4, 23.0, 46.0], [7.0,14.0,?,2.0], ['*', '*', 8.9, 6.4]]

newList = [[11.0, 25.4, 330.3, 340.0], [1.6, 23.4, 23.0, 46.0]]
```

Comment: In my instance, it is simply these characters: * ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) within `list comprehension` to filter out `list`s that have `str`s using [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
>>> testList = [[30.0, '?', 910.0, 120.],[11.0, 25.4, 330.3, 340.0], [1.6, 23.4, 23.0, 46.0], [7.0,14.0,'?',2.0], ['*', '*', 8.9, 6.4]]
>>> [subL for subL in testList if not any(isinstance(val, str) for val in subL)]
[[11.0, 25.4, 330.3, 340.0], [1.6, 23.4, 23.0, 46.0]]
```

Comment: A variant of this answer can be to check to have only floats : [ sublist for sublist in testList if not any(type(i)!=float for i in sublist)]

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a qualifier function, then use list comprehension to create the new list?

```
def keep_me(element):
    # analyze the element, and return True to keep, or False to drop
    return True
```

Then to use:

```
filtered_list = [x for x in original_list if keep_me(x)]
```